# Can "found" be used, as it is in this sentence, in the future tense?

Tags: future

For example,

> After several years, Rubin left to *found* Danger, Inc.

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: Isn't this in the past tense?

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely not future tense.

Comment: I didn't know how to construct my question.. Sorry.

Comment: I know that it isn't the future tense.

Comment: "To found" is in the infinitive. *Left* is in the past tense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> After several years, Rubin left to *found* Danger, Inc.

Yes, that’s grammatically correct. It’s not the future tense, though. *Left* is past tense, and *to found* is the infinitive. The sentence describes something that has already happened.

But the future *will found* is fine too:

> The male (small, dark ant) will soon die, and the queen will found a new colony.
>
> The link between the two works is the Trojan hero Aeneas, but more specifically, it is his ultimate mission that impels him to leave Dido and Carthage for Italy where he will found the Roman empire as a new Troy.
>
> FIVB critics will found new federation in Copenhagen

The last is a [headline](http://www.playthegame.org/news/detailed/fivb-critics-will-found-new-federation-in-copenhagen-1242.html); the other two are from *[COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)*.

Comment: (+1) for an accurate answer and strong examples.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Found is the present tense of a verb meaning to establish or create a company or institution.